# WCF Test Client Failed to Invoke

Tags: c#, wcf

Attempting to invoice a method that will run an Oracle Query and return the result however I'm getting an internal error which I assume based on what I've read in the stack trace is related to a conversion of some sort however I'm trying to get a list as a string. The value is a varchar2 in the database. Here is my stack trace:

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IMyService.GetMeterBlinkData()
   at MyServiceClient.GetMeterBlinkData()
```

So I'm not really sure what is not being converted right in this. **I've tried to use the value of int i**n my code but that doesn't seem to solve my problem either as I get the same stack trace. Perhaps I need to convert this in my code before I get to this point?

Here is my code:

```
    public List<string> GetMeterBlinkData()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        string oradb = "Data Source=********;User Id=****;Password=****;";
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);  // C#
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "select t2.meternumber, t1.blinkdate, t1.blinkcount from (select * from cecc_processed_blinks where trunc(blinkdate) between to_date('01-may-15', 'dd-mon-yy') and to_date('08-may-15', 'dd-mon-yy')) t1 left join meteraccts t2 on t1.serialnumber = t2.serialnumber order by t1.blinkdate desc";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        //TODO loop through results and fill the results object
        conn.Dispose();

        return result;
    }
```

Here is my IMyService.cs:

```
namespace BlinkDetails
{  
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<string> GetMeterBlinkData();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

At this point I have enabled logging by using           `<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />` and I'm now getting an error from my WCF Test Client before the service will even run that says the following:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service MyService.  Add a ServiceMetadataBehavior to the configuration file or to the ServiceHost directly to enable support for this contract.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupContract(String contractName, String serviceName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress, Boolean skipHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader configLoader, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceSection)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.ApplyConfiguration()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.CreateServiceHost(Type type, ServiceKind kind)
   at Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.OpenService(ServiceInfo info)
```

**Here is the app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="BlinkDetails.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="debug">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/BlinkDetails/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="BlinkDetails.IMyService">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="debug">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You didn't post the most important part of your code - how you fill the `List<string>`.   Also, what is the actual exception message?  I don't see anything in the stack trace that indicates a conversion problem.

Comment: The list should be the "result" no? Here is the actual message: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Comment: Yes, it should be - but if something happened while creating/filling the list, then it would result in an internal error.  Two other things to do - do as the exception says and turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (and/or enable WCF Tracing), and check the Event Viewer to see if any errors were logged there.

Comment: Okay I understand. I've enabled it and it mentions not having a valid contract for IMetedataExchange however that is setup as an endpoint here:         <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service MyService.  Add a ServiceMetadataBehavior to the configuration file or to the ServiceHost directly to enable support for this contract.

Comment: Update your question with the full error message and post your service and client configs, please.

Comment: Did you know that there is a program called "WCF test client"? Is that what you refer to in your title?

Comment: Yes, the test client is what I'm getting errors on.

Comment: How are you hosting the service?  Based on the config file, it looks like you have a WCF Service Library.   Can you post the app.config/web.config for the application that is hosting the service?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the problem is in your endpoint definition - 
contract="IMetadataExchange"

Change this to be the fully qualified name of your contract 
contract="BlinkDetails.IMyService"

Comment: OP has two endpoint definitions - one for the service, referencing `BlinkDetails.IMyService` as the contract and one for the metadata exchange, referencing `IMetadataExchange` as the contract.